# Help identifying the resistor

Tags: pcb, identification, components

Can someone help me with identifying this component please? I was initially under the impression that it is a resistor but when I look at the back, it looks like a resistor with a dab of solder in between. I have tried to find a circuit diagram for the board but failed. I looked up a 5 band resistor but the colors don't match. Thanks in advance.

Edit 1: Here is a circuit diagram I found- the components are at D3.
http://www.lcdrepairguide.com/V5/ak_2017/temp/tempfiles_/PSU_Schematic_Diagram/Samsung%20BN44-00358B%20PSU%20Schematic.pdf

[image: Circuit representation]

[image: Unknown Component/Resistor]

Comment: It does look like a 650 mohm resistor with a 250 ppm/K rating but I am not sure.

Comment: sounds right.. the white stuff is firm polyurethane (PU) adhesive as a large part stiffener to protect the solder joint PTH connection from  a microbarrel open cct.

Comment: dab of solder between what?

Comment: @RahulKorpu - you're reading the colors in the wrong order -it's  0.56Ohm.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 I was referring to the solder on the other side of the PCB. The solder in between the resistance symbol.

Comment: @jsotola I am referring to the solder on the other side (green) of the PCB. The solder in between the resistance symbol.

Comment: that solder pad goes no where but could be just a 1pF series cap

Comment: The solder appears to just be a blob stuck to an unused pad (test point?). Looks like there is a burn mark at the right end of the resistor. Why do you need to identify it?

Comment: @BruceAbbott I am looking to replace the burnt components on the board. The board is a SMPS of a LED tv. As of now I can identify that a control IC and a resistor are burnt.

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 You are correct about that. I had finally managed to find the circuit diagram and it does show that it is a 1W 0R65 resistor. http://www.lcdrepairguide.com/V5/ak_2017/temp/tempfiles_/PSU_Schematic_Diagram/Samsung%20BN44-00358B%20PSU%20Schematic.pdf

Comment: Yes Rahul, A Rare time when @KevinWhite got it reversed (not 0.56)

Comment: @KevinWhite I tried to read it again but the problem is there isn't any 4/5 band resistors starting with black and continuing with gold and silver. The only other feasible solution is to start with blue (6) green (5) Silver (0.01 ohm) Gold (+-5%) and black (250 ppm/K) = 0.65 ohm. Why do you think it is a 0.56 ohm resistor? Thanks!

Comment: Found by coordinate D3 .. RS816 0R65 1W but I wonder why CD814 has an unsoldered pin  0.1uF

Comment: @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 The component is an IC S801. I have just looked at the vendor drawing and it says one of the pin is not connected by default. I am sorry if I am not understanding your question correctly. https://www.infineon.com/dgdl/Infineon-ICE3BR0665J-DS-v02_03-en.pdf?fileId=db3a30431a5c32f2011a7a6233036886

Comment: ok................